# Learning Swift with Coredata: why don't I get any UITableViewCells?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, core-data, nsurlconnection

I transitioned my recent Swift-self-learning project from using an NSMutableArray to using CoreData.

What I want my program to perform is:

- Connect to a login/passwd protected page and download a list of the most recent 100 pics along with their timestamp
- For each pic in this list, create an NSManagedObject (PicInfo) (if there's no existing object containing the same pic url - not implemented yet, I guess it has to do with an NSPredicate).
- Display each of these objects ordered by descending timestamp in an UITableView

Though I used to have a [little issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623920/uitableview-refresh-problems-with-an-nsurlconnection-asynchronously-laden-nsmuta) with the initial non-CoreData (I had to touch the UITableView to have it display anything and the refresh was hanging the app, it's become worse with CoreData: the UITableView remains empty altough I know I am storing objects:

```
Got data!
Refresh will start
MVC::insertNewObject beginning
PicInfo init: found 0: [viewz/CAM_HALL_1_20150225074135_4324.jpg] taken at 2015/02/25 07:41:35
MVC::insertNewObject about to insert Object 0 - http://my.webcam.site.perso/CAM_HALL_1_20150225074135_4324.jpg
2015-02-25 07:41:55.497 spEye[21867:2544527] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UITableView.m:1377
2015-02-25 07:41:55.498 spEye[21867:2544527] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update with userInfo (null)
MVC::insertNewObject successfully inserted Object 0 - http://my.webcam.site.perso/CAM_HALL_1_20150225074135_4324.jpg
MVC::insertNewObject beginning
PicInfo init: found 1: [viewz/CAM_HALL_1_20150225074129_4323.jpg] taken at 2015/02/25 07:41:30
MVC::insertNewObject about to insert Object 1 - http://my.webcam.site.perso/CAM_HALL_1_20150225074129_4323.jpg
MVC::insertNewObject successfully inserted Object 1 - http://my.webcam.site.perso/CAM_HALL_1_20150225074129_4323.jpg
MVC::insertNewObject beginning
PicInfo init: found 2: [viewz/CAM_HALL_1_20150225074124_4322.jpg] taken at 2015/02/25 07:41:24
MVC::insertNewObject about to insert Object 2 - http://my.webcam.site.perso/CAM_HALL_1_20150225074124_4322.jpg
MVC::insertNewObject successfully inserted Object 2 - http://my.webcam.site.perso/CAM_HALL_1_20150225074124_4322.jpg
...
Refresh completed
```

So I am really stuck and afraid to lose patience and get back to Objective-C. Would somebody be kind enough to take a look to my code and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here's the code:

**MasterViewController**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

let baseUrlString = "http://my.webcam.site.perso"
let username = "mylogin"
let password = "v3rys3cr3tp4s$"

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController,NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate,NSURLConnectionDataDelegate {

    var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil
    var loading: Bool = false;


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
            self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
            self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 320.0, height: 600.0)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        if let split = self.splitViewController {
            let controllers = split.viewControllers
            self.detailViewController = controllers[controllers.count-1].topViewController as? DetailViewController
        }
        self.refreshControl?.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        self.refresh(self)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject, details: NSString) {
        println("MVC::insertNewObject beginning")
        let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
        let entity = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entity!
        var picInfo=PicInfo(data: details)
        println("MVC::insertNewObject about to insert Object \(picInfo.index) - \(picInfo.url)")

        let newManagedObject = picInfo.managedObject(entity, context:context)

        // Save the context.
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if !context.save(&error) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            println("MVC::insertNewObject *could not* insert Object \(picInfo.index) - \(picInfo.url)")
            abort()
        }
        println("MVC::insertNewObject successfully inserted Object \(picInfo.index) - \(picInfo.url)")
    }

    // MARK: - Segues

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as NSManagedObject
                let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController).topViewController as DetailViewController
                controller.detailItem = object
                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table View

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (self.fetchedResultsController.sections?[section] as? NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo)?.numberOfObjects ?? 0
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        self.configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return false
    }

    func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
       if let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? PicInfo {
            println("configureCell: \(object.index)")
            var todo=""
            if (object.downloading || !object.downloaded) {
                todo="(*)"
            }
            cell.textLabel!.text = "\(object.index): \(object.desc)\(todo)"
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = object.stamp
            if (!object.downloaded) {
                object.loadImage()
            }
            if var img = object.image{
                cell.imageView?.image = img
            }
        } else {
            println("configureCell: object#\(indexPath.row) not found !?")
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Fetched results controller

    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
        if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
            return _fetchedResultsController!
        }

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
        // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("PicInfo", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!)
        fetchRequest.entity = entity

        // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 100

        // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "stamp", ascending: false)
        let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
        // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
        let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

        var error: NSError? = nil
        if !_fetchedResultsController!.performFetch(&error) {
             // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
             // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
             println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error?.description)")
             abort()
        }

        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }    
    var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil

    func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
        switch type {
            case .Insert:
                tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            case .Delete:
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            case .Update:
                if let thecell=tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) {
                    println("MVC::didChangeObject: cell exists at \(indexPath?.row)")
                    self.configureCell(thecell, atIndexPath: indexPath!)
                } else {
                    println("MVC::didChangeObject: nil cell at \(indexPath?.row)\n\(tableView.description)")
            }
            case .Move:
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            default:
                return
        }
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    /*
     // Implementing the above methods to update the table view in response to individual changes may have performance implications if a large number of changes are made simultaneously. If this proves to be an issue, you can instead just implement controllerDidChangeContent: which notifies the delegate that all section and object changes have been processed.

     func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
         // In the simplest, most efficient, case, reload the table view.
         self.tableView.reloadData()
     }
     */

    // MARK: - Refresh
    func refresh(sender:AnyObject)
    {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.loadPictureList()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    // MARK: Internet stuff

    func loadPictureList () {
        // set up the base64-encoded credentials
        if (self.loading) {
            return
        }
        self.loading = true
        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
        let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)
        let authString = "Basic \(base64LoginString)"
        config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

        // create the request
        let url = NSURL(string: baseUrlString + "/latest.php")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)

        // fire off the request
        var task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!){
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                self.handlePictureList("", encounteredProblem:"\(error.localizedDescription)\nurl:\(url)")
            } else {
                var result = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
                self.handlePictureList(result, encounteredProblem:"")
            }
        }
        task.resume()

    }

    func handlePictureList (data: NSString, encounteredProblem error: NSString) {
        if (error.length>0) {
            println ("Had error: [\(error)]")
        } else {
            println ("Got data!")
            println("Refresh will start")
            var pixArr = data.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
            for unparsedPicInfo in pixArr {
                if (unparsedPicInfo.hasPrefix("<tr>")) {
                    var picInfo=unparsedPicInfo.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("<tr><td>", withString: "")
                    picInfo=picInfo.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("</td></tr>", withString: "")
                    picInfo=picInfo.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("</td><td>", withString: "\t")
                    self.insertNewObject(self, details:picInfo)
                }
            }
            self.loading = false
            println("Refresh is over")

        }
        return
    }

}
```

**PicInfo**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

class PicInfo {
    var index: Int = 0
    var desc: String = ""
    var stamp: String = ""
    var url: String = ""
    var image: UIImage!
    var downloaded: Bool = false;
    var downloading: Bool = false;

    init(data: String) {
        var picInfos=data.componentsSeparatedByString("\t")
        println("PicInfo init: found \(picInfos[0]): [\(picInfos[2])] taken at \(picInfos[1])")
        self.index = picInfos[0].toInt()!
        self.url = baseUrlString + "/" + picInfos[2]
        self.stamp = picInfos[1]
        desc = ""
        if (picInfos[2].rangeOfString("CAM_HALL") != nil) {
            desc="Hall"
        } else if (picInfos[2].rangeOfString("CAM_STAIRS") != nil) {
            desc="Stairs"
        } else {
            desc="Cats"
        }
        self.image = UIImage(named: "nothingtosee")
        self.loadImage()
    }

    func URL() -> NSURL {
        var URL=NSURL(string: self.url)
        return URL!
    }

    func managedObject(entity: NSEntityDescription, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> NSManagedObject {
        let newManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entity.name!, inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
        newManagedObject.setValue(index, forKey: "index")
        newManagedObject.setValue(desc, forKey: "desc")
        newManagedObject.setValue(stamp, forKey: "stamp")
        newManagedObject.setValue(url, forKey: "url")
        newManagedObject.setValue(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,80), forKey: "image")
        newManagedObject.setValue(downloaded, forKey: "downloaded")
        newManagedObject.setValue(downloading, forKey: "downloading")

        return newManagedObject;
    }

    func loadImage() {
        if (self.downloading) {
            return
        }
        let url = self.URL()
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
        let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)

        // create the request
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        self.downloading = true
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,data: NSData!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if let blob = data {
                    self.image = UIImage(data: blob)
                    self.downloaded = true
                }
            }
            else {
                println("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            self.downloading = false
        })
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**
Added the numberOfRowsInSection method.

Now the UITableView displays records (default values) but crashes just before I can interact (and empties the TableView).

The log give:

```
Got data!
Refresh will start
MVC::insertNewObject beginning
PicInfo init: found 0: [viewz/00D6FB01ABB1()_1_20150225175206_7382.jpg] taken at 2015/02/25 17:52:05
MVC::insertNewObject about to insert Object 0 - http://my.site.perso/00D6FB01ABB1()_1_20150225175206_7382.jpg
configureCell: object#0 not found !?
MVC::insertNewObject successfully inserted Object 0 - http://my.site.perso/00D6FB01ABB1()_1_20150225175206_7382.jpg
MVC::insertNewObject beginning
PicInfo init: found 1: [viewz/00D6FB01ABB1()_1_20150225175200_7381.jpg] taken at 2015/02/25 17:52:00
MVC::insertNewObject about to insert Object 1 - http://my.site.perso/00D6FB01ABB1()_1_20150225175200_7381.jpg
configureCell: object#1 not found !?
MVC::insertNewObject successfully inserted Object 1 - http://my.site.perso/00D6FB01ABB1()_1_20150225175200_7381.jpg
MVC::insertNewObject beginning
PicInfo init: found 2: [viewz/00D6FB01ABB1()_1_20150225175155_7380.jpg] taken at 2015/02/25 17:51:55

....snip....

MVC::insertNewObject beginning
PicInfo init: found 11: [viewz/00D6FB01ABB1()_1_20150225175109_7371.jpg] taken at 2015/02/25 17:51:08
MVC::insertNewObject about to insert Object 11 - http://my.site.perso/00D6FB01ABB1()_1_20150225175109_7371.jpg
configureCell: object#11 not found !?
MVC::insertNewObject successfully inserted Object 11 - http://my.site.perso/00D6FB01ABB1()_1_20150225175109_7371.jpg
MVC::insertNewObject beginning
PicInfo bad packing
init: found 12: [viewz/00626E423E6A()_1_20150225175018_4683.jpg] taken at 2015/02/25 17:50:19
bad packing
bad packing
MVC::insertNewObject about to insert Object 12 - http://my.site.perso/00626E423E6A()_1_20150225175018_4683.jpg
bad packing
MVC::didChangeObject: nil cell at Optional(12)
<UITableView: 0x7fea05030000; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fea0333c180>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fea03337d90>; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {320, 572}>
MVC::insertNewObject successfully inserted Object 12 - http://my.site.perso/00626E423E6A()_1_20150225175018_4683.jpg
MVC::insertNewObject beginning
PicInfo init: found 13: [viewz/00626E423E6A()_1_20150225175007_4682.jpg] taken at 2015/02/25 17:50:18
MVC::insertNewObject about to insert Object 13 - http://my.site.perso/00626E423E6A()_1_20150225175007_4682.jpg
MVC::insertNewObject successfully inserted Object 13 - http://my.site.perso/00626E423E6A()_1_20150225175007_4bad packing
682.jpg
MVC::insertNewObject beginning
PicInfo init: found 14: [viewz/00626E423E6A()_1_20150225175002_4681.jpg] taken at 2015/02/25 17:50:03
MVC::insertNewObject about to insert Object 14 - http://my.site.perso/00626E423E6A()_1_20150225175002_4681.jpg
MVC::insertNewObject successfully inserted Object 14 - http://my.site.perso/00626E423E6A()_1_20150225175002_4681.jpg
MVC::insertNewObject beginning
PicInfo init: found 15: [viewz/00626E423E6A()_1_20150225174957_4680.jpg] taken at 2015/02/25 17:49:58
MVC::insertNewObject about to insert Object 15 - http://my.site.perso/00626E423E6A()_1_20150225174957_4680.jpg
MVC::insertNewObject successfully inserted Object 15 - http://my.site.perso/00626E423E6A()_1_20150225174957_4680.jpg
MVC::insertNewObject beginning
PicInfo init: found 16: [viewz/00626E423E6A()_1_20150225174952_4679.jpg] taken at 2015/02/25 17:49:52
MVC::insertNewObject about to insert Object 16 - http://my.site.perso/00626E423E6A()_1_20150225174952_4679.jpg
bad packing
MVC::insertNewObject successfully inserted Object 16 - http://my.site.perso/00626E423E6A()_1_20150225174952_4679.jpg
MVC::insertNewObject beginning
bad packing
PicInfo init: found 17: [viewz/00626E423E6A()_1_20150225174946_4678.jpbad packing
g] taken at 2015/02/25 17:49:47
bad packing
bad packing
bad packing
bad packing
MVC::insertNewObject about to insert Object 17 - http://my.site.perso/00626E423E6A()_1_20150225174946_4678.jpg
MVC::didChangeObject: nil cell at Optional(17)
<UITableView: 0x7fea05030000; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fea0333c180>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fea03337d90>; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {320, 572}>
MVC::didChangeObject: nil cell at Optional(17)
<UITableView: 0x7fea05030000; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fea0333c180>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fea03337d90>; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {320, 792}>
MVC::insertNewObject successfully inserted Object 17 - http://my.site.perso/00626E423E6A()_1_20150225174946_4678.jpg
MVC::insertNewObject beginning
PicInfo init: found 18: [viewz/00626E423E6A()_1_20150225174941_4677.jpg] taken at 2015/02/25 17:49:42

....snip....

MVC::insertNewObject beginning
PicInfo init: found 23: [viewz/00626E423E6A()_1_20150225174920_4673.jpg] taken at 2015/02/25 17:49:21
MVC::insertNewObject about to insert Object 23 - http://my.site.perso/00626E423E6A()_1_20150225174920_4673.jpg
MVC::insertNewObject successfully inserted Object 23 - http://my.site.perso/00626E423E6A()_1_20150225174920_4673.jpg
MVC::insertNewObject beginning
PicInfo init: found 24: [viewz/QOQA_CAM_UPLOADX_2015022517492001.jpg] taken at 2015/02/25 17:49:20
MVC::insertNewObject about to insert Object 24 - http://my.site.perso/QOQA_CAM_UPLOADX_2015022517492001.jpg
MVC::insertNewObject successfully inserted Object 24 - http://my.site.perso/QOQA_CAM_UPLOADX_2015022517492001.jpg
MVC::insertNewObject beginning
PicInfo init: found 25: [viewz/00D6FB01ABB1()_1_20150225174857_7370.jpg] taken at 2015/02/25 17:48:57
MVC::insertNewObject about to insert Object 25 - http://my.site.perso/00D6FB01ABB1()_1_20150225174857_7370.jpg
MVC::didChangeObject: nil cell at Optional(25)
<UITableView: 0x7fea05030000; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fea0333c180>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fea03337d90>; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {320, 1012}>
```

I think the background fetch is somehow strange: it begins with systematical "object not found" message and the comic hash-soup fall at the end, when it crash.

Am I doing something wrong while creating new managed objects?

Comment: Where are your tableView datasource methods? They should be returning row and section counts from your fetched results controller

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's a good question. I remember removing the one about the sectioncount (which I first modified to return 1 but it did not change anything tot he result and error logged) but I don't think the other one was ever present from the xcode generated mvc swift file.

Comment: In Interface Builder, can you check that both `delegate` and `dataSource` properties of your `UITableView` are connected to your `MasterViewController`?

Comment: That's still not a crash log. You should be seeing some sort of error in the console when this stops. If you're using background threads, note that you can't use managed objects across threads, but that's a whole other question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did many things to my code since yesterday and it kinda works now:

1. storing the webcam pics to a temporary directory instead of coredata. I did this because I could not find out how to defer the MOC saving operation until the NSManagedObject would have downlaoded its own pic.
2. I also realized I was not dealing with my PicInfo objects but rather with NSManaged object. I then wrote some bridge procedures in order to get the MO from the PI object and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

You're not implementing the correct table view datasource methods. Because you've subclassed `UITableViewController`, which has base implementations of the methods, you don't see a warning, but you'll be returning one section and zero rows regardless of the data you hold.

It looks like you only have one section, so you can leave that, but you need this method:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return return (fetchedResultsController?.sections?[section] as? NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo)?.numberOfObjects ?? 0
}
```

This gives the number of rows for a section. If you know you'll only have one section, you could just use

```
return fetchedResultsController?.fetchedObjects?.count ?? 0
```

Which is a bit less horrible.

Comment: IT crashes: I get this: <<UUITableView: 0x7fe8c283700I0T;a bflreaVmiee w=:  (00x 70f;e 83c2208 3576080)0;;  cflriapmseT o=B ounds (=0  Y0E;S ;3 2a0u t5oresize = W6+8H);;  gcelsitpusrTeRecogniozBeorusn d=s  <=N SArrayY:E S0;x 7afuet8ocr1e5s5idz2e1 0=> ;W +lHa;y egr = <CALaeysetru:r e0Rxe7cfoeg8c155a820>; ncioznetresn t=O f<fNset: {0,S A-64}; conrtreanyt:S i0ze: x{73f2e08,c 165458d5261}0>>
; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fe8c155a820>; contentOffset: {0, -64}; contentSize: {320, 64856}>

Comment: It happens during the didChangeContent() call, at the endUpdates().

Comment: That's not a crash log, and what on earth happened to it? it looks like something went a bit strange with copying and pasting...

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I edited the post. That's funny how it finally finds objects when it reaches the 12th or so... They might still be downloading...